# Silverlight - Programmatically Resolving Binding Expression

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, controltemplate

Is there any way to programmatically resolve a binding expression? I have a templated control that has a lot of complicated inner workings that I do not want to expose. It takes a list, and exposes a template for a full item view, and some details to modify the individual item templates. I'd like to have three properties on my control as binding paths, so I can expose a template as follows:

```
<src:MyControl x:Name="MyControl" 
               FullViewTemplate="{StaticResource FullViewTemplate}"
               TopValueBinding="Items[2]"
               BottomValueBinding="Items[6]"
               CategoryBinding="Items[5]"/>
```

Inside, I would like to take the whole datacontext and supply it to a value converter, which will resolve my configurable binding path. Something like this:

```
PropertyPath path = new PropertyPath("Items[0]");
var value = Convert.ToDecimal(path.Resolve(dataSource));
```

I currently use the property name and reflection to extract values, but this does not have the flexibility to work with complex data types, and I don't want to have to write a massive block of parsing and reflection logic to retrieve field values.

EDIT: Alternatively, being able to do something like this would be great:

```
{Binding Path={TemplateBinding BottomValueMember}, Converter={StaticResource ScaleValueConverter}}
```

But this does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - after much digging I resolved this with the following code:

```
    public class BindingEvaluator : DependencyObject
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Target",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(BindingEvaluator),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private object Target
    {
        get { return GetValue(TargetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
    }

    private static BindingEvaluator _instance = new BindingEvaluator();
    private static BindingEvaluator Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public static object Eval(Object instance, string path)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(path) { Source = instance };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(Instance, TargetProperty, binding);

        return Instance.Target;
    }
}
```

Credit to the answer from this post: [Is there a way to get a property value of an object using PropertyPath class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877171/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-property-value-of-an-object-using-propertypath-class)

Now I just pass the whole data item in and have the converter take care of it.