# Alternative to using PropertyPath to find a DependencyProperty + instance?

Tags: c#, xaml, reflection, binding, storyboard

I am trying to write some generic code that augments a Storyboard. As part of that, I want to be able to get the DependencyProperty that is referenced by TargetProperty. The purpose is to set the value of the dependency property programmatically.

.NET has a great class for doing that - PropertyPath does the work it seems like.. However, it's almost completely private and so you cannot really access it w/o reflection.

Is there an alternative anyone knows of?

(i.e. Given the TargetProperty of "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" and a given object, I want to get a DependencyProperty + object that corresponds to the TranslateX property of the CompositeTransform instance that resides on the RenderTransform property of the object I provided)

Edit: Changed from PropertyInfo to DependencyProperty

Comment: > However, it's almost completely private: `public sealed class PropertyPath`. ??

Comment: All the interesting members that may have helped me do what I want are private. I should have been more specific. Sorry.

Comment: I see. May be, this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877171/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-property-value-of-an-object-using-propertypath-class

Comment: Awesome. Not what I meant, but good enough for me. Thanks.