# Set member from code using property path

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, system.reflection

I'm looking for a way to set a specific member of a class or a struct specified using a binding path like this SomeStruct.AnotherStructs.Item[0].Str . I basically want to be able to do what WPF does through binding, both reading and writing values, but from code.

I've made some attempts to use BindingEvaluator (see [Is there a way to get a property value of an object using PropertyPath class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877171/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-property-value-of-an-object-using-propertypath-class) and http://iist.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/TP/QuickChartsWPF/BindingEvaluator.cs) but was unable to get it to update the source value. I've also tried using BindingExpression.UpdateSource but that also failed.

I've looked at various proposal to use reflection for this. Is reflection the way to go or is there some existing mechanism that I can use to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: "of a class or a struct" -- you're going to run into problems updating structs.  You'll end up updating a boxed copy of the original struct instance; your changes will not propagate back to the original source.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've already bumped into that problem :) . Unfortunately there is nothing I can do about that. I'm going to have to find a way to make it work, if not automatically then manually.

Comment: Make what work?  You're not going to be able to update structs unless you can load the address of the original.  Structs simply do not behave the way classes do, and the only way you're going to be able to update arbitrarily nested struct values is with some nasty runtime IL generation, and if the struct is exposed by a property, you're screwed.  Don't use structs for mutable data.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. The only way what worked for me by propagation of struct/class members value change from code to WPF controls was:

- a create a new instance of typeof(SomeStruct)
- copy all SomeStruct member values to new instance
- overwrite the desired member values
- assign this new instance to SomeStruct
- NotifyPropertyChanged

Only in that case the related WPF controls showed new values specified by code - I used a TextBox, ComboBox selection with Binding to SomeStruct members as typed in the initial question.